# Switching projection to d3.geoMercator() causes errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to plot the US counties from a topojson file located at: https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json using d3.js v4.5.0 and topojson v2.  The default project in d3 is Albers (I think).

Using the following code produces a standard projection map:

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 600;

var svg = d3.select("#us-county-map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geoPath();

d3.json("data/us_counties.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

[image]

However, when changing `var path` to:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(500)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);
```

It produces 799 errors of type:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…61.126408983549,NaNL1559.4690422…"
```

and the following graphic (yes, a black box).

[image]

What is creating the errors, and is there a proper way to do apply the projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see a map displayed without a defined projection, it is because the data is *already* projected:

```
var path = d3.geoPath();
```

This can also be represented as:

```
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(null);
```

D3 projections project coordinates with latitude and longitude, that is points on a 3 dimensional earth. Projected data such as yours has been converted to a two dimensional surface, and does not need to be projected. D3's projection function will not be able to correctly project it.

To use a d3 projection, you need to ensure that you are using WGS84 as your spatial reference system (or coordinate reference system). That is to say that your data is measured in latitudes and longitudes.

Note that is possible to manipulate already projected data by using a geoTransform, see the [API reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoTransform) and this block [on reprojecting already projected data](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5663666).

---

Edit:

Because the specific data in this question is projected in a composite projection (allowing inclusion of Hawaii and Alaska), it may be hard to unproject. It may be easier to find county data and convert it to topojson.

One source of county boundaries is [here](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html). These shapefiles can easily be converted by adding all the parts of the shapefile into [mapshaper.org](http://mapshaper.org/) and exporting as a topojson. While it does use a NAD83 datum, rather than a WGS84 datum, the difference should be fairly minute. But, if needed it is possible to convert to WGS84 in mapshaper by using the console and typing `proj wgs84`. A demonstration of this data is found here: [US Counties Bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/ddcda63d769f8e1d61fa5105346f983f)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  So I would need to know the original projection of the json data before transforming it?

Comment: That would help, but this is a fairly unique and complex type of projection, combining several projections into one. It may be easier to find county data elsewhere and convert it to topojson or geojson. With your mercator projection you tested in the question, be sure to use a center coordinate that is near the center of the US to ensure your data is in view, something like `.center([-100,40]), but keep in mind Alaska and Hawaii may be out of view.